# How do I compare a character to check if it is null?

Tags: java

I tried the below, but Eclipse throws an error for this.

```
while((s.charAt(j)== null)
```

What's the correct way of checking whether a character is `null`?

Comment: A `char` is a primitive. `null` is reserved for unasigned references.

Comment: Is `s` String? If so `s.charAt` will return primitive type `char`, not object `Character` so it can't be null. Default values of `char` array are `'\u0000'` or simpler `'\0'`. You could even use `s.charAt(j) == 0`

Comment: Are you trying to check for the end of the String as in C?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check that the `String` `s` is not `null` before doing any character checks. The characters returned by `String#charAt` are primitive `char` types and will never be `null`:

```
if (s != null) {
  ...
```

If you're trying to process characters from `String` one at a time, you can use:

```
for (char c: s.toCharArray()) {
   // do stuff with char c  
}
```

(Unlike `C`, `NULL` terminator checking is not done in Java.)

Answer (score 10):

Default value to char primitives is 0 , as its ascii value. 
you can check char if it is null. for eg:

```
char ch[] = new char[20]; //here the whole array will be initialized with '\u0000' i.e. 0
    if((int)ch[0]==0){
        System.out.println("char is null");
    }
```

Comment: `char` cannot be null because it's not a reference type. It's a primitive.

Answer (score 8):

Correct way of checking `char` is actually described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21502884/1708390).

It states:

> Change it to: `if(position[i][j] == 0)`
>   Each `char` can be compared with an `int`.
>   The default value is `'\u0000'` i.e. 0 for a `char` array element.
>   And that's exactly what you meant by empty cell, I assume.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the null character (`'\0'`):

```
while((s.charAt(j)=='\0')
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually came here from reading a book "Java: A Beginner's Guide" because they used this solution to compare char to null:

```
(char) 0
```

Because in ASCII table, null is at the position of 0 in decimal.

So, solution to OP's problem would be:

```
while((s.charAt(j) == (char) 0)
```

I also tried out the already offered solution of:

```
while((s.charAt(j)=='\0')
```

And it also worked.

But just wanted to add this one too, since no one mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare with default char value

```
while((s.charAt(j) != '\u0000')
```

Answer (score -3):

If `s` is a string and is not null, then you must be trying to compare "space" with char. You think "space" is not a character and space is just `null`, but truth is that space is a character. Therefore instead of `null`, use  (which is a space) to compare to character.

Comment: Besides that the question is 2.5 yrs old, I find it *highly* unlikely that they're looking for a space.