# How can I check if the char array has an empty cell so I can print 0 in it?

Tags: java, loops, char, compare, charat

**Code:**

```
public void placeO(int xpos, int ypos) {
    for(int i=0; i<3;i++)
        for(int j = 0;j<3;j++) {
            // The line below does not work. what can I use to replace this?
            if(position[i][j]==' ') {
                position[i][j]='0';
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Compare it with `Character.UNASSIGNED` - not ' ' or 0.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change it to: `if(position[i][j] == 0)`
Each char can be compared with an int.
The default value is `'\u0000'` i.e. `0` for a char array element.
And that's exactly what you meant by `empty cell`, I assume.

To test this you can run this.

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[][] x = new char[3][3];
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<3; j++){
                if (x[i][j] == 0){
                    System.out.println("This char is zero.");
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have initialized your array like

```
char[] position = new char[length];
```

[the default value for each `char`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) element is `'\u0000'` (the **null character**) which is also equal to `0`. So you can check this instead:

```
if (postision[i][j] == '\u0000')
```

or use this if you want to improve readability:

```
if (positionv[i][j] == 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 if(position[i][j]==0)
{
 // The index value of [i][j] is 0
}
```