# How to check if a char is null

Tags: java, android

I want to check if the char is null or not? but why this code is not working? `letterChar == null` also is not working. I googled for many problems but didn't see any solutions, mostly the solutions are about `String`.

```
String letter = enterletter.getText().toString();
char letterChar = letter.charAt(0);


if(letterChar == ' ' || letterChar == NULL) // this is where the code won't works
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a letter!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Char? Why not use string?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523284/java-string-replace-and-the-nul-null-ascii-0-character

Comment: @statosdotcom because I want the user to enter character only

Comment: You can achieve you result wit this:
`String letter = enterletter.getText().toString().trim();`
// this will remove whitespace


`if(letter.length()<1){
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a letter!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}`

Comment: @burger , check the answer below it will work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `char` cannot be `null` as it is a primitive so you cannot check if it equals `null`, you will have to find a workaround.

Also did you want to check if `letterChar == ' '` a space or an empty string? Since you have a space there.

The first two answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14844793/how-do-i-compare-a-character-to-check-if-it-is-null?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) may be helpful for how you can [either](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14844836/9530790) check if `String letter` is null first.

[or](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39391055/9530790) cast `char letterChar` into an int and check if it equals `0` since the default value of a char is `\u0000`- (the nul character on the ascii table, not the null reference which is what you are checking for when you say `letterChar == null`)- which when cast will be `0`.

Answer (score 2):

char is a primitive datatype so can not be used to check null.

For your case you can check like this.

```
        if (letterChar  == 0) //will be checked implicitly
        {
            System.out.println("null");
        }
        //or use this
        if (letterChar  == '\0')
        {
            System.out.println("null");
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

From your code it seems like you work with Unicode and the method you search for is into *Character* class (java.lang)

```
Character.isLetter(ch);
```

It also contains lots of useful static method that can suite you.
If so, the code will be

```
String letter = enterletter.getText().toString();
char letterChar = letter.charAt(0);

if(!Character.isLetter(letterChar))
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a letter!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

But if I would need to answer your question (without taking a look to your aim), then the code you need depends on what do you mean by "is char null".

In Java char cannot be == null.
If you want to check if it is not an empty space, you need to do

```
 if (ch == ' ')
```

If you want to check if there are no line breakers (space, HT, VT, CR, NL and other), you should add the following to the proposed above:

```
if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\r' || ch == '\n' || ch == '\x0b')
```